# Kivy - problem with buildozer build on android - C preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

i'm trying to build my kivy app on my mac using buildozer but when running command `sudo buildozer android debug` i get an error:

`configure: error: C preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See config.log' for more details`

can somebody help me?

here is full log: https://pastebin.com/wbrSfirV

and here is my buildozer.spec file: https://pastebin.com/f4YwerZt

and code: https://github.com/KarolBorecki/Decode

you can see there is warning "missing libtoolize", but i dont know is that a problem?

Thanks everyone for help!

Comment: The API version you're targeting is far too new for your NDK.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. I changed my ndk version to r18 and now i get that one error: https://pastebin.com/K5TG3r3P my cython version is 0.27.3.